# Let $f(x,y,z)$ be a convex function. Is the reciprocal convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose that $f(x,y,z)$ be a convex function. Prove $\frac{1}{f(x,y,z)}$ is convex. Or give an example of $f$ where $1/f$ is not convex.

For example, I know that $f(x,y,z)=(1+x^2)\sqrt{1+y^2+z^2}$ is convex on $\mathbb R^3.$  $g=1/f$  is not convex  on $\mathbb R^3? $

$f$ convex implies the inequality
$f(x, y+v, z+w) - f(x,y,z) \geq f_y(x,y,z) + f_z(x,y,z)$ for all $x,y,z,v,w \in \mathbb R$.

However $g=1/f$ does not satisfy the inequality  $g(x, y+v, z+w) - g(x,y,z) \geq g_y(x,y,z) + g_z(x,y,z)$ for x=0, y=1, z=1, v= -2, w=-2 . Thus it is not convex in $\mathbb R^3$.

Therefore in general $1/f$ is not convex. Any comments?

Comment: You mean reciprocal of the function, not its inverse. right?

Comment: yes, the reciprocal, ill fix it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is false in general, even in one dimension.  A smooth function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex iff $f''(x) > 0$, but
$$ \left(\frac{1}{f}\right)'' = \left(-\frac{f'}{f^2} \right)' = -\frac{f''}{f^2} + \frac{2f'^2}{f^3}$$
Thus, for example, if $f' = 0$, and $f'' > 0$, $f$ is convex but its reciprocal is not.

Comment: if f is less than zero, it would be convex, right? How would I show f is not convex(in general) if f was a multivariable function, particularly 3 variables f(x,y,z)? thanks

Comment: That should be $(1/f)'' = (-f'/f^2)' = -f''/f^2 + 2f'^2/f^3$. If $f'=0$ then the reciprocal of $f$ is not convex regardless of the sign of $f$.

Comment: what would be an example of a function with those conditions f>0, f'=0, f''>0. thanks +1

Comment: $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: Oops, thanks for the correction.

Comment: so it would only be not convex at x=0? and convex everywhere else?

Comment: No, $1/(x^2 + 1)$ is nonconvex in a neighborhood of $x = 0$, since if the second derivative is negative at $x = 0$ it is negative nearby by continuity.