# Multiplicative inverse (or reciprocal) of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, inverse

Consider the following theorem and proof.

Theorem

Let Γ be a convex and compact set in $R^n$, let f be a strictly positive convex numerical function, and let $F(x)=1/f(x)$ . Then F(x) is convex.

Proof

If we assume that F(x) is convex, by definition of convex function we have

$F\left( {\theta x + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)y} \right) \leqslant \theta F\left( x \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)F\left( y \right)$

For $x,y\, \in \,dom\,F$ and $0 \leqslant \theta  \leqslant 1$
By replacing $F(x)=1/f(x)$

$\frac{1}{{f\left( {\theta x + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)y} \right)}} \leqslant \theta \frac{1}{{f\left( x \right)}} + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)\frac{1}{{f\left( y \right)}}$

After some manipulation we have

$f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) \leqslant f\left( {\theta x + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)y} \right)\left( {\theta f\left( y \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)f\left( x \right)} \right)$

Since $f\left( x \right)$ is a convex function

$\begin{gathered}
  f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) \leqslant f\left( {\theta x + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)y} \right)\left( {\theta f\left( y \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)f\left( x \right)} \right) \hfill \\
  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \leqslant \left( {\theta f\left( x \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)f\left( y \right)} \right)\left( {\theta f\left( y \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)f\left( x \right)} \right) \hfill \\
  \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\ = \left( {{\theta ^2} + {{\left( {1 - \theta } \right)}^2}} \right)f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) + \left( {1 - \theta } \right)\theta \left( {{f^2}\left( y \right) + {f^2}\left( x \right)} \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

After some manipulation and simplification

$\begin{gathered}
  {f^2}\left( x \right) + {f^2}\left( x \right) - 2f\left( x \right)f\left( y \right) \geqslant 0 \hfill \\
  {\left( {f\left( x \right) - f\left( y \right)} \right)^2} \geqslant 0 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $

Since this condition is true, hence F(x) is convex.

End of proof

But the above proof does not seem to apply in all cases.

For example: $f\left( x \right) = {x^2} + 1$ .

Any comments or insights as to why this is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $x^2 + 1$ is not a decreasing function, and thus does not satisfy your hypotheses. Is that what you're asking? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: Thank you David for your prompt reply. You are correct, I should not have mentioned 'decreasing', I edited my question by removing it. The theorem is general and should apply to all cases (increasing and decreasing convex functions).  The main question which still remains is why the proof does not apply in general.

Answer (score 1):

The theorem is false, as the case $f(x)=x^2+1$ shows.

You need to read your "proof" backwards, since you wanna show that something true implies
$$
F(\theta x+(1-\theta)y) \le \theta F(x) + (1-\theta)F(y).
$$
You correctly show that
$$
\big[\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)\big]\big[\theta f(y) + (1-\theta)f(x)\big] \ge f(x)f(y),
$$
and that
$$
\big[\theta f(x)+(1-\theta)f(y)\big]\big[\theta f(y) + (1-\theta)f(x)\big] \ge f\big(\theta x+(1-\theta)y\big) \big[\theta f(y) + (1-\theta)f(x)\big]
, $$
but you can't conlude from this that
$$
f\big(\theta x+(1-\theta)y\big) \big[\theta f(y) + (1-\theta)f(x)\big] \ge f(x)f(y),
$$
which is what you need.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406357/620957).